# Getting a String From a website

Tags: c#

Hi I'm trying to write a program where I could get my public ip address from http://ifconfig.me/ip

but my code fails.. the program compiles but when I press the button to get the ip and display it on a txtbox the program is frozen I have tried the following code

```
using system.xml;
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("http://ifconfig.me/ip");
string allText = document.InnerText;
```

and my other code is

```
using system.net
WebClient abc = new WebClient();
txtMyIp.Text = abc.DownloadString("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip");
```

can any one tell me why the program freezes when I press the button? or suggest me any other way/method?

btw I am using visual studio 2012

Comment: *but both codes fail* how exactly are they failing?

Comment: by fail I mean they compile but they don't do anything, when the button is clicked the program freezes

Comment: That is important information, freezing is not the same as doing nothing

Comment: Downloading the website with the XmlDocument will throw an exception, because what you get from it is not xml. The second approach just takes ages but works.

Comment: Your second method worked for me.  It was quite slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your UI freezes because you downloading string from website in UI thread, which means that your UI thread can only wait unitl your `abc.DownloadString("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip");` executes.
   Istead of that I would recommend you to use async/await and `HttpClient` from `System.Net.Http`. Your code would look like this:

   ```
   private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (var abc = new HttpClient())
       {
          var uri = new Uri(@"http://www.ifconfig.me/ip");
          txtMyIp.Text = await abc.GetStringAsync(uri);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Note that you can do the same with `WebClient` by calling `abc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri)`, but `HttpClient` should be quicker because it doesn't contain the stuff related with web browser simulation like `WebClient`.
3. Also note that with both APIs you should dispose your client by wrapping it in using statement because it has to free some resources, for example close the stream opened for incoming data.
4. If you are using .NET Framework of version less that 4.5 and want to use WebClient - try this code snippet, it shouldn't freeze your UI:

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (var abc = new WebClient())
       {
           var uri = new Uri(@"http://www.ifconfig.me/ip");
           abc.DownloadStringCompleted += (o, args) => txtMyIp.Text = args.Result;
           abc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
       }
   }
   ```
5. I noticed that sometimes `http://www.ifconfig.me/ip` returns permanent redirect to `http://ifconfig.me/ip`, thus I think you should use address without www.

Answer (score 3):

It is the website that causes to do it. Its just taking ages to load.
You should try using another website: `http://wtfismyip.com/text`
I've tried

```
string myIP = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://wtfismyip.com/text");
```

and it worked fine.

Comment: Try [WhatsMyIp](http://www.whatsmyip.org/). Its a lot faster then the one you are trying to screen scrape from.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

String url = "http://ifconfig.me/ip";
String responseFromServer = null;
try
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream))
                responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
catch { }

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(responseFromServer))
    MessageBox.Show(responseFromServer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried in the LINQPad with success (remember to add the `System.Net` namespace):

```
void Main()
{
    var  client = new WebClient();
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://www.ifconfig.me/ip"));
}
```

Result:

```
177.156.151.233
```

PS:
Linqpad: https://www.linqpad.net/

Answer (score 0):

You should try downloading the string asynchronously:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://ifconfig.me/ip");
XmlDocument xmlDocument = await XmlDocument.LoadFromUriAsync(uri);
string result = xmlDocument.ToString();
```